# wget not found from OSX script run from Java

Tags: java, sh, wget

I've written a Java program that runs a script on my Mac:

```
     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
     String cmdString = "./load_test.sh";

     System.out.println(cmdString);
     Process pr = rt.exec(cmdString);

     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                               pr.getErrorStream()));

     String line = null;
     while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
     {
        System.out.println(line);
     }

     int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
```

The load_test script does this:

```
wget -O/dev/null --load-cookies cookies-$1.txt 'http://demo.mycompany.co.uk/userhome'
```

Even though I've run load_test.sh on my Mac from many different locations, the output of this Java program is:

> ./pcm_load_test.sh: line 2: wget: command not found

So, it seems that when spawned from Java, wget can't be called from a script?

I thought this might be a user-access issue so I tried:

```
 sudo chmod a+rwx /usr/local/bin/wget
```

but this had no effect.

Any ideas why `wget` won't run from the script called from a Java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch), and based on my own experience with running scripts on multiple OS via an application:

When executing a script via java code, you must make sure that the command you are trying to execute can be found. This generally requires the usage of one of two options:

- Using a global environment path variable - when running a script programmatically, your code opens a shell instance and executes your script. The new shell instance has no preconfigured global environment path variable, which means you should add this configuration to the start of your script:
  `export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/your/used/bin`
- Use the absolute path to your command - simply explicitly call your command with its full path in your script: `/usr/local/bin/wget ........`

As a side note - the error message in the OP states that the `wget` command cannot be found. An attempt to provide full read/write/execute permissions via `chmod` will, indeed, have no effect since the permissions do not help with providing a path to the command.

References:

- [PATH to WGET](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6293498)
- [Where to Set Environment Variables in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/28/set-enviornment-variables-mac-os-x/)
- [How to execute shell command from Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/)